# html/css designed box not lining up properly

Tags: php, html, css

Tonight, I am going to start making my [website](http://dragontoothsoftware.com) more professional looking and start adding content. The first issue I would like to adress is one that has been bugging me for a long time. If you go to my website, you will see that the boxes are off centered (and floating to the left) while everything else is lining up in the center. ive gone over my html/css/php code, but I can't figure out the issue (Web based programming is not one of my strong suits, however I would rather learn and code it myself instead of paying someone to do it for me). Anyways, the generated html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Dragon Tooth Software</title>

        <link rel="icon"       href="/images/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/banner.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/box.css" />

        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="1OG6sLqFnSg_Azq0tJjkpqPklx0KhO1cu7S5ii60FKc" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
    <a href="/index.php"><img src="/images/banner.jpg" height="100px" width="925px" /></a>
    <h1>Dragon Tooth Software</h1>
    <h2>Rule the Web</h2>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
<li class="current"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="projects.php">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="tutorials.php">Tutorials</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

    <div class="content-box">
<h1 class="header">Welcome to Dragon Tooth Software</h1><p class="content">Greetings! I am DTSCode!</p>
</div><br /><div class="content-box">
<h1 class="header">Thursday, July 17<sup>th</sup>, 2014</h1><p class="content">www.dragontoothsoftware.com is officially open!</p>
</div><br />    </body>
</html>
```

and the css file that makes up the box:

```
.content-box {
    float: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 10px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: Add a fiddle please or some links to check

Comment: a link to the site? i did. look at website in the first line

Comment: my mistake. i forgot to write the closing tag. ill edit it promptly

Comment: I see the box in the center. Only thing left aligned i see is the text "Greetings! I am DTSCode!"

Comment: Can you replicate this in a jsFilde (http://jsfiddle.net/), as once your site is fixed the link is useless.

Comment: I'd suggest using a framework like bootstrap, which gives you a nice grid layout to use for your design, and solves many browser compatibility issues, as well as giving you a responsive design which works on both mobile devices and larger screens.

Comment: Add margin-left:40px to content box

Comment: Jon P: sure. always love it when people come across my problems and find solutions. is float: center not a valid style code hushme? and thanks user. ill try that

Comment: More handy hints... strive for only 1 `h1` per page. `h2` is probably more appropriate for your use here, i.e.  section headers. Also don't use `<br />` for spacing use CSS margins instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the default margin and padding values from the `UL` tag in the `NAV` element.

```
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: wouldnt that target the navigation bar though?

Comment: Yes but that is what is off center. Essentially you are looking in the wrong place. The content boxes are centered perfectly. The unordered list in the navigation has default padding and margin values that need to be overridden. These values are currently forcing the menu to the right of center which gives the appearance that the boxes are at fault. Use developer tools in chrome to inspect the page and see for yourself.

Comment: i see now. my mistake. it had looked like the box was off center. thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You an try below code:

```
ul{padding:0; margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below css to normalize css and create a wrapper class.

CSS :

```
    /*limited reset*/
    html, body, div, section, article, aside, header, hgroup, footer, nav, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, address, time, span, em, strong, img, ol, ul, li, figure, canvas, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    }

   .wrapper{ width:960px; margin:0 auto; }
```

Follow the below html structure

HTML

```
            <nav>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <ul>....</ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="content-box">...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Also there is no property as `float:center`. Use `float:left` or `float:right` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

the boxes are not off centered and floating to the left. the difference is due to the default padding in the UL tag. another thing is that you have not defined any width to the boxes, so a div will be, by default, 100% in width. you can define a specific width and then centrally align it.